# unrecognized external symbol getImageLibVersions

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, leptonica

I have followed this [link](http://www.leptonica.org/vs2008doc/quickstart.html) to get started with executing leptonica programs.However I am getting the following output when I run either of the cl commands given on the page.

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hellolept.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hellolept.exe
/LIBPATH:..\..\..\..\lib
zlib125-static-mtdll.lib
libpng143-static-mtdll.lib
libjpeg8c-static-mtdll.lib
libtiff394-static-mtdll.lib
giflib416-static-mtdll.lib
liblept168-static-mtdll.lib
hellolept.obj
hellolept.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol getImagelibVersions re
ferenced in function main
hellolept.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol getLeptonicaVersion re
ferenced in function main
hellolept.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I am working on a 64 bit windows.All the libraries mentioned in the above error are present in the lib folder.What might be the issue here?

The commands I have tried are (first one identical to what's on link above):

```
cl /O2 /I "..\..\..\..\include" /I "..\..\..\..\include\leptonica" 
   /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /FD /EHsc /MD hellolept.c
   /link /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\lib" liblept168.lib
```

and:

```
cl /O2 /I "..\..\..\..\include" /I "..\..\..\..\include\leptonica" 
   /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /FD /EHsc /MD hellolept.c
   /link /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\lib" zlib125-static-mtdll.lib 
   libpng143-static-mtdll.lib libjpeg8c-static-mtdll.lib 
   libtiff394-static-mtdll.lib giflib416-static-mtdll.lib 
   liblept168-static-mtdll.lib
```

Comment: Please show the command(s) you ran.  Have you checked that the libraries are indeed at `..\..\..\..\lib`?

Comment: Yes The libraries are present.

Comment: I see `helloept.obj` appear after the `.lib`s. Make sure you put `helloept.obj` before the libraries in your compile/link commands.

Comment: The commands I have tried are cl /O2 /I "..\..\..\..\include" /I "..\..\..\..\include\leptonica" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /FD /EHsc /MD hellolept.c /link /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\lib" liblept168.lib OR cl /O2 /I "..\..\..\..\include" /I "..\..\..\..\include\leptonica" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /FD /EHsc /MD hellolept.c /link /LIBPATH:"..\..\..\..\lib" zlib125-static-mtdll.lib libpng143-static-mtdll.lib libjpeg8c-static-mtdll.lib libtiff394-static-mtdll.lib giflib416-static-mtdll.lib liblept168-static-mtdll.lib. There is no reference to .obj file here

Comment: Please add your program in your post; NOT as comment. I don't see anything wrong for now.